# When is the algebraic closure a colimit?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, field-theory

Let $k$ be a field. We know that there exists an algebraically closed field $\bar{k}$ containing $k$ such that $\bar{k}/k$ is algebraic. This is the algebraic closure of $k$.

Usually this is constructed as the quotient of a huge polynomial ring. Nevertheless, I know that in some cases we can write $\bar{k}$ as the (directed) colimit of all finite subextensions of $\bar{k}/k$. (This is a colimit in the category of extensions of $k$. Not a colimit in the category of fields, I think.) This should hold for finite fields, if I recall correctly.

I now wonder two things:

1. Under which conditions on $k$ does this result holds?
2. If it holds, does it means that $\bar{k}$ is equal to the union of every finite subextension of $k$?

Comment: When the set of irreducible polynomials $\in K[x]$ is countable then $\overline{K}=\bigcup_{n\ge 1} L_n$ with $L_n/K$ a finite extension and $L_n\subset L_{n+1}$. When it is not countable, to avoid quotienting a polynomial ring in uncountably many variables you'll set $\overline{K}=\bigcup_{F\in S} F$ where $S$ is the set of finite normal extensions of $K$, for $E,F\in S$ then $E$ is the splitting field of $h_E\in K[x]$, if $h_E$ splits in $F$ then we need an embedding $\sigma_{E,F}:E\to F$, and those embeddings need to satisfy $\sigma_{F,M}\circ \sigma_{E,F}=\sigma_{E,M}$.

Comment: This way $a\in E$ defines uniquely an element $\sigma_{E,M}(a)$ of all finite normal extensions where its minimal polynomial splits, whence an element of $\overline{K}$.

Comment: @reuns what's the problem in quotienting a polynomial ring with uncountably many variables? Also, just to be clear, you're implying that 1. and 2. are both true when $k$ has only countable many irreducible polynomials and are both false otherwise?

Comment: None and no. ${}{}{}$

Comment: So both 1. and 2. are always true by your first construction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For *any* field $K$ and any directed family of subfields $(F_i)_{i\in I}$ (directed here meaning that for any $i$ and $j$, there exists a $k$ such that $F_i\cup F_j\subseteq F_k$), if $K = \bigcup_{i\in I} F_i$, then $K$ is the colimit in the category of fields of the diagram consisting of the $(F_i)_{i\in I}$ and the inclusion maps between them.

In particular, for any field $k$, the algebraic closure $\overline{k}$ is the directed colimit (in the category of fields) of the diagram consisting of all of its subfields which are finite extensions of $k$.

Typically, for categories of algebraic structures, the forgetful functor to $\mathsf{Set}$ preserves directed colimits. So if we have a directed diagram where the arrows are inclusions, the underlying set of the directed colimit will just be the union of the underlying sets of the structures in the diagram.

To make this more precise: For any $\forall\exists$-axiomatizable first-order theory $T$, the category $\text{Mod}(T)$ of models of $T$ and embeddings has directed colimits, and the forgetful functor to $\mathsf{Set}$ preserves directed colimits. And for any *positive* $\forall\exists$-axiomatizable theory $T$, the category $\text{Mod}(T)$ of models of $T$ and homomorphisms has directed colimits, and the forgetful functor to $\mathsf{Set}$ preserves directed colimits. Note that the category of fields is $\forall\exists$-axiomatizable, and every homomorphism of fields is an embedding.

Comment: Crucially, though, this doesn't actually give a *construction* of an algebraic closure.  It only works if you already have one and are considering its subfields; if you start with just the category of extensions of $k$, then you don't know what diagram to take a colimit of if you don't already have an algebraic closure (or something equivalent).

Comment: @EricWofsey Good point. Of course to construct the algebraic closure in general, one needs a choice principal. I haven't tried to write down the details, but it seems plausible to construct the algebraic closure of $k$ as a directed colimit like this: Consider the collection of all splitting fields of polynomials in $k[x]$. The diagram of all such fields and all embeddings between them is not directed. But by a compactness argument, we can choose a coherent system of embeddings, and then the directed colimit will be the algebraic closure of $k$.